# How can i disable past weekends in Jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker

I have a calendar that shows only weekends to select...
But i want to disable past weekends... 
Example: Now is day 30, but calendar shows weekends before today date...

[Example here](http://entrestaciones.es/prueba-formulario/)

And how to add festive days?

Here´s the code:

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){
        jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            firstDay: 1,
            currentText: 'Hoy',
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié;', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: '',
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var day = date.getDay();
                return [(day == 0 || day == 6)];
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For disable dates that are festive days, I think you'll have to add an array with those dates, maybe you can pull them out from a database or hardcode them, heres an example:

```
var festiveDays = ["15-2-2014","23-2-2014","2-3-2014"];
```

As for showing only dates after "today" just add `minDate: 0` to datepicker. Now if you want to combine them both, this is the final result:

```
// Festive days dates (lets use these three days as example)
var festiveDays = ["15-2-2014","23-2-2014","2-3-2014"];

// Initialize datepicker
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
        var dates = dt.getDate() + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+1) + "-" + dt.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dates, festiveDays) < 0) {
            return [dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6, ""];
        } else {
            return [false,"",""];
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxzBT/) so you can test it.

[image: Final result]

Comment: Hi Tomatrox!
Thanks so much for your answer...
I have tried "minDate:0" and it works fine!
But if i try "var day = date.getDay();
                return [(day == 0 || day == 6)];" before the code i put above, then don´t works because have a javascript conflict...how can i fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update your code? Or upload it on a jsfiddle? So I can see where's the error.